# Pass object to ng-click inside of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm struggling getting an object to pass through to a directive and then used within an ng-click attribute. The HTML and directive is below. As written, the ng-class attribute gets rendered "correctly" as `ng-class="{ 'my-class': selectedItem === {"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Snow"} }"`

However, the ng-click directive gets rendered incorrectly as `ng-click="selectedItem = value"`

I can't use `{{value}}` inside the ng-click directive or it throws an error stating `Token '{' invalid key at column 17 of the expression [selectedItem = {{value}}] starting at [{value}}]."`

I tried switching this around and using a link instead of a template and using scope.value. This would return `[object Object]` as at that point I'm concatenating strings.

The HTML:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
        <td>
            <check-box ng-model="selectedItem" behavior="radio" value="item"></check-box>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('check-box.directive', [])
    .directive('checkBox', checkBoxDirective);

    function checkBoxDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: template
    };

    function template(element, attributes) {

        var baseHtml = '<button type="button" ';
        var ngClass = 'ng-class="{ \'my-class\': ' + attributes.ngModel + ' === {{value}} }"';
        var ngClick = 'ng-click="' + attributes.ngModel + ' = value"';

        return baseHtml + ngClass + ngClick + '></button>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to have your button's ng-click do? Maybe we can suggest other ways of doing it...

Comment: lose the curly braces around value in the template function `{{value}}` should be {{value}}

Comment: @wdanda It's just supposed to assign the object provided in the value attribute to the object provided in the ng-model attribute

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution:

```
    var ngClick = `ng-click= "${attributes.ngModel} = ${value}"`;
```